# How can I make the iOS simulator battery show 100%?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I noticed that applications run in the Xcode simulator will inherit the battery level and charging status from the OS of the host machine.  Is there any way to override or set the battery level when running in the simulator?

I did come across this module here, but I am looking for a simpler solution that would give me more customization according to my needs for different iPhones. https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic

Comment: There is no supported mechanism to do this today.

Answer (score 18):

As of Xcode 11 (beta 4), you can use the command line to set time and battery level.
`xcrun simctl status_bar <device> override --time "9:41" --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100`

See the *Simulator New Features* section in [Xcode 11 beta 4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes)

Comment: To change level for a booted device `xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "9:41" --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 30`

Comment: Just for clarification: If you run the simulator for an iPhone 8, you should run the following code in the command line: xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 8" override --time "8:00" --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100

Comment: Valid values for the `batteryState` option: `charging`, `charged`, `discharging`. (To see the options,  run at the command line: `xcrun simctl help status_bar`.)

Comment: I thought this wasn't working because the simulator (14.3) with iPhone 14 Pro always shows 100% no matter the laptop's battery level. But when I do `xcrun simctl status_bar booted list` it actually reports `Battery State: 2, Battery Level: 30, Not Charging: 0` - so that's pretty confusing